# Geodesical completness of the Spatial Schwarzschild manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics

I need to show that the Spatial Schwarzschild manifold $\big(M:=\mathbb{R^3} \backslash \{0\}, (1+\frac{m}{2s})^4\delta\big)$. (where $\delta$ is the Euclidean metric on $M$ in spherical coordinates, $m>0$, and $s(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the radial component) is geodesically complete.

I was thinking if I could prove that it is compact, then that would prove the statement but with no luck so far, so maybe there is an easier approach which I can't see.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: M is not compact right ?

Comment: @Sou that's right it is not.

Comment: Since $M$ is connected Riemannian manifold, you could try to show that there exist $p \in M$ such that the exponential map $\text{exp}_p$ defined for all $v \in T_pM$. This will implies that $M$ is metrically complete and hence by Hopf-Rinow $M$ is geodesically complete. (Beware i'm a noob so dont take this too seriously).

Comment: @Sou I will give that a go, thanks.